# how to change JSON data format in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, bootstrapping

I am new to Angular JS.

My JSON data is:

```
{
"CheckList": [
   {
    "UnitClass": "Budget Space",
    "CheckListCategoryId": 1,
    "CheckListCategory": "DOORS",
    "CheckListItemId": 2,
    "CheckListItem": "Deadbolt, Locksets, and keys all functioning"
   }, 
   {
    "UnitClass": "Budget Space",
    "CheckListCategoryId": 2,
    "CheckListCategory": "WINDOWS",
    "CheckListItemId": 46,
    "CheckListItem": "Windows are operable"
   }, 
   {
    "UnitClass": "Budget Space",
    "CheckListCategoryId": 2,
    "CheckListCategory": "WINDOWS",
    "CheckListItemId": 13,
    "CheckListItem": "Window pane is not broken or cracked"
   }
}
```

And I want to change it to:

```
{
"CheckList": [
   {
    "UnitClass": "Budget Space",
    "CheckListCategoryId": 1,
    "CheckListCategory": "DOORS",
    "CheckListItemId": 2,
    "CheckListItem": "Deadbolt, Locksets, and keys all functioning"
   }, 
   {
    "UnitClass": "Budget Space",
    "CheckListCategoryId": 2,
    "CheckListCategory": "WINDOWS",
    "CheckListItems": [
        {
            "CheckListItem": "Windows are operable",
            "CheckListItemId": 46,
        },
        {
            "CheckListItem": "Window pane is not broken or cracked",
            "CheckListItemId": 13,
        }]
   }
}
```

Why I am doing this:

I have a Bootstrap collapse list as

DOORS
WINDOWS

which i am getting using ng-repeat, adding a filter 'unique' on `CheckListCategoryId`

But the problem is with my current JSON, only single `CheckListItem` is getting posted but in many cases there are two. like in WINDOWS.

How to change the JSON data??

One more thing.
Is my current way correct or there is any other alternative??

Comment: If you are going to work with angular you need to learn how to manipulate arrays using javascript. Also a good chance that if you control the source data you should be mapping it better there

Comment: I don't understand if you have this json as a response to a request on the server or something else? if you get it as a response from a server then change the server method, or iterate over deserialize the structure and change it as you will, if this is not the problem, then be more specific please.

Comment: actually that REST API is not in my hand and this is how I will get the data. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupBy` from [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) to group your data. Then you can filter your data by category like this `ctrl.checkList | groupBy: 'CheckListCategory'`.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/7z7nj08x/).

I've used a bootstrap accordion to display the data but collapse should also work. I'm not sure how it should look like with the collapse that's why I used an accordion.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular.filter'])
 .controller('MainController', MainController);
function MainController($http, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    
 $http.jsonp('http://www.mocky.io/v2/56183175100000e5387222f9?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
     vm.checkList = response.data[0].CheckList;
     });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/a8m/angular-filter/master/dist/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <uib-accordion>
        <uib-accordion-group heading="{{cat[0].CheckListCategory}}" ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.checkList | groupBy: 'CheckListCategory'">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in cat">
                    {{item.CheckListItem}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! That really helped me.